# vertical dotted line ascii or unicode character

Tags: unicode, terminal, ascii

I'm trying to find a vertical dotted line ascii character. Currently I'm using `¦` but am hoping to find something more along the lines of the indent guide character that sublime text has:

[image]

Definitely doesn't have to be exact, but I'd like it to be more of a dotted line than a dashed line.

Comment: Such lines are typically made by drawings on the window's background, not using character strings at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yea, I know, but that wasn't an option for my application and I wanted to achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Funkotron_King said, there is nothing better in ASCII, if Unicode is an option you could use U+250B - ┋

Comment: it turns out I can use Unicode for this. I edited the question.

Comment: It won’t probably create a regular line though: there will usually be gaps between the strings of four dots. You would need to experiment with different fonts.

Answer (score 15):

There are a lot symbols like this at http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=VERTICAL

such as: ⁞, ⋮, ┆, ┊, ┋, ┇, ︙,

I was looking for symbol like ⁞ but 6 dots whose name is "vertical six dots" and code point is U+2E3D, unfortunately, I was not able to copy/paste it here like others, since I couldn't get it displayed in my browser. If you know, please paste it in the comment section.

Comment: @rld. Are your browsers able to display that symbol? My browsers are not.

Comment: This is U+2E3D: ⸽

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only dotted vertical line in ASCII is the colon (:) Html code &#58 hex code 3A.

For a list of all the ASCII chars follow this link.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Hope that helps